How can I get data from the current Dataverse environment in a Power Platform Dataflow?
I've developed a Power Platform dataflow that fetches work item data from Azure DevOps and merges it with some local data from the same Dataverse environment that the Dataflow is in, to update some tables used for reporting. My problem is, I have the Dataverse URL as a parameter, but that means it gets overwritten each time I promote a change from Dev to Test or Prod. So, I figure I need to do one of two things:

Put the Dataverse url somewhere that it won't be overwritten. I know that Dataflows can't use Environment Variables. Is there anything akin to a Power Platform Environment Variable that I can use to keep the dataverse URL after redeploying the Dataflow?
Change the way the Dataverse data is fetched in the Dataflow so that it's explicitly from "this environment" and not an environment specified in a parameter that will be overwritten. Is this possible?

Is there a solution to this? Can a Power BI Dataflow accomplish this?
I've looked extensively at documentation for Dataflows, but I see no options to connect directly to the current environment, or to keep a consistent value across redeployments of a Dataflow.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
